# fabricjs free drawing sensitive

Tags: fabricjs

When drawing a number 0 or a small circle do not draw
please see issue: https://i.ibb.co/yFD8CNL/photo-2019-03-29-01-34-42.jpg

```
fabricjs demo link: https://codepen.io/ShahramCodeDeveloper/pen/MxNzPp
```

fabricjs screenshot: https://i.ibb.co/yFD8CNL/photo-2019-03-29-01-34-42.jpg

this work correct on paperjs: https://i.ibb.co/7v9ncXw/0.jpg

paperjs demo link: [https://codepen.io/kunukn/pen/mVRVWd](https://i.ibb.co/yFD8CNL/photo-2019-03-29-01-34-42.jpg)

where is problem?

Comment: can you update codepen link with reproducing issue ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/ShahramCodeDeveloper/pen/MxNzPp